# When using FireFoxDriver in Selenium, How to Know The Page Url?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, nunit, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using FireFoxDriver, C#, NUnit and Selenium.

My test method starts by going to a page and performing some actions then the user will be redirected to another page.

How to verify whether the page redirection has occured?

```
this.FireFoxWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
// performing some actions
// todo: how to verify the page url now?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ah, so simple!

Assert.AreEqual(this.FireFoxWebDriver.Url, expectedRedirectUrl);